# ItextSharp fit text to a page

Tags: c#, text, itext

i'm italian and i'm sorry for my english.
I'm trying to use itextSharp to convert a txt file into pdf file.
this is my code:

```
String l = file.ReadLine() + "\r\n";
while (l != null)
{
  iTextSharp.text.Font contentFont = iTextSharp.text.FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL);
  //Chunk line = new Chunk(l, contentFont);
  Paragraph p2 = new Paragraph(l,contentFont);
  oDoc.Add(p2);
  oDoc.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
  l = file.ReadLine();
}
oDoc.Close();
```

The text page is a multi page file, so I would like to reproduce the same on the pdf file.

When i read "Page 2" on my txt file, I need to create a new page in the pdf file.

I would like to put all the text before page 2 in only one pdf page.

How can i fit all the text in only one pdf page?

Thank's so much and sorry for my english

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you reach the end of a text page before the end of a PDF page, you can just call `oDoc.newPage()`.  The alternative isn't so simple.

The only Easy Way To Do It would be to create a text field on each page, with the multiline flag set.  You then set the font size to zero and the field will automatically pick a font size that will size the font to fit the available space (within some reasonable limits).

You could also use a `ColumnText` and call `go(true)`.  This will "simulate" layout allowing you to make adjustments to the actual font size prior to actually drawing the text to a content stream.