# Trying to convert plain text file to iTextSharp without losing format

Tags: c#, itext

I am trying to convert text files to PDF with iText Sharp.
The conversion itself is not a problem however, I am unable to create the PDF file such that it looks exactly the way the text in the text file is aligned.

This is the code I am using:

```
public void GetPDF(string data)
    {

        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            Rectangle docSize = new Rectangle(612, 798);
            Document myDocument = new Document(PageSize.A4.Rotate());

            PdfWriter.GetInstance(myDocument, new FileStream
                                         ("MyNewPDF.pdf", FileMode.Create));

            // step 3:  Open the document now using
            myDocument.Open();

            // step 4: Now add some contents to the document
            myDocument.Add(new Paragraph(data));
            myDocument.Close();
        }
    }
```

Does anybody have a suggestion as to what to do to simply convert a text file into PDF without losing the format of the text file?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I am a little confused as to what the MemoryStream `ms` is used for. (Or is `data` the same thing just misnamed when adding the new Paragraph?)

Comment: See also [Convert txt to pdf in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4906455/161052) (Closed) or [ItextSharp fit text to a page](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4805767/161052).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to make your PDF file use a mono spaced font like Courier New.

Comment: So, this is almost working now. At the bottom of each page the page number is displayed. After the fifth page the page number is not shown at the bottom anymore but at the beginning of page 6. Any suggestions?

Comment: @J.Barras, are the page numbers part of your text file? If so, then your calculation for what contents fit on a page is off.

Comment: Same question I was going to ask, I don't believe ITextSharp adds headers/footers (with or without page numbering) by default.

Answer (score 0):

A plain text file contains no formatting. When you refer to how the text is aligned, I have to presume you are viewing the text file with a fixed-width or monospace font. Therefore when you convert the text file to PDF, you should specify that a fixed-width/monospace font is used (such as Lucida Console, Courier New, Consolas, etc.)

Next, word wrap is not generally specified in a plain text file. Long paragraphs of text will end with a carriage return/newline character and that's it. The PDF conversion is likely to introduce some word-wrapping at the page boundaries. To control this you will need to select a font size that wraps where you want it, or insert some CR/LF's manually.