# Adding text to a PDF file from a text file

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, itext

This is my code:

```
        using (FileStream msReport = new FileStream(pdfPath, FileMode.Create))
        {
            //step 1
            using (Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 140f, 10f))
            {
                try
                {
                    // step 2.
                    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("TextFile.txt");
                    string line;
                    PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, msReport);
                    pdfWriter.PageEvent = new ITextEvents();

                    //open the stream 
                    pdfDoc.Open();

                    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                    {
                        if ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                        {
                            Paragraph para = new Paragraph(line, new iTextSharp.text.Font(iTextSharp.text.Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 6));

                            para.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;

                            pdfDoc.Add(para);

                            //pdfDoc.NewPage();
                        }
                    }
                    sr.Close();
                    pdfDoc.Close();
```

and it's working...It reads the text file that is in my computer and adds it to PDF... The problem is - it doesn't keep the formatting from the text file. It just adds text. And I need to keep it the way it is. Is there any way to keep the formatting of the text? Can I somehow add it to a table and format the table, or something like that?

Comment: Define *formatting of the text*. The *formatting* of so-called plain text is usually artificial. Are you talking about tabs? Then you have to replace them with spaces (because a tab character doesn't mean anything in PDF). Are you talking about spaces? Then you need to use a mono-space font. Are you talking about markup (similar to what you use to create a Stack Overflow question)? Then you need to parse that formatting syntax first (using another tool).

Comment: I think this question is a duplicate of [Convert TXT file to PDF using iText (keep formatting)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26925856) and that the actual answer is the answer I gave to the question [How to set monospaced font by using iTextSharp?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34495221/how-to-set-monospaced-font-by-using-itextsharp)

Comment: I should have been more specific, I'm sorry. The text is formatted like a table, with various amount of spaces between...and it's written in C#...

Comment: OK, in that case, I'll mark the question as duplicate. You should use `iTextSharp.text.Font.FontFamily.COURIER` instead of `iTextSharp.text.Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA`.

Comment: Will try it, not sure if that is going to fix it...

Comment: As I thought, it didn't fix the problem.

Comment: What is wrong with that solution? It works for other people. You aren't giving us a clear description of your problem: you don't show us the input (the formatted txt file); you don't show us the output. All you are telling us, is *it doesn't work*, but [doesn't work is not a problem description that a software developers should give when asking a question.](http://lowagie.com/doesntwork) See also [Trying to convert plain text file to iTextSharp without losing format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6988034)

Comment: Maybe you've overlooked my comment: **Are you talking about tabs? Then you have to replace them with spaces (because a tab character doesn't mean anything in PDF).**

Answer (score 2):

Try this one

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using iTextSharp;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf; 

namespace TxtToPdf
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Read the Data from Input File

            StreamReader rdr = new      StreamReader("Path/Test.txt");

           //Create a New instance on Document Class

            Document doc = new Document();

           //Create a New instance of PDFWriter Class for Output File

           PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new  FileStream("Path/Test.pdf", FileMode.Create));

           //Open the Document

            doc.Open();

           //Add the content of Text File to PDF File

           doc.Add(new Paragraph(rdr.ReadToEnd()));

           //Close the Document

           doc.Close();


           //Open the Converted PDF File

           System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("Path/Test.pdf");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by reading escape sequence too like when line changes you should Read it as \n and then write it in PDF with your text.

Comment: It would surprise me if that's the answer. I think this question is a duplicate of [Convert TXT file to PDF using iText (keep formatting)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26925856) and that the actual answer is the answer I gave to the question [How to set monospaced font by using iTextSharp?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34495221/how-to-set-monospaced-font-by-using-itextsharp)

Comment: the link u proided is also using escape squence  :/ like i said.

Comment: Er... you are talking about newline characters. Those aren't the problem. If you wrap a `String` containing newline characters inside a `Paragraph`, you will see newlines in the resulting PDF. The main problem people usually have, is that they are using a proportional font (in the case of the OP, it's Helvetica) instead of a mono-spaced font (e.g. Courier). Your answer doesn't reflect that in any way.