# C# - Save XML's plain text as PDF instead of converting

Tags: c#, xml, pdf

I am trying to save XML's plain text into PDF file.
For example,
this is how my XML file looks like.
[image: This is how xml file looks like]

I literally want that plain text save as PDF. Format should look the same as when I open XML file in the browser. How would I do that using C#? I couldn't really find solution. I would very much appreciate your help!

Comment: Your answer in that post doesn't say anything about C# code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# - Save XML file as PDF as Raw Image (not converting)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68838756/c-sharp-save-xml-file-as-pdf-as-raw-image-not-converting) **Don't open multiple accounts and repost the same question**